# Android Studio Swipe to different views

Tags: java, android, android-studio, fragment, swipe

I'm new beginner using Android studio I have currently watched a couple tutorials on setting up a basic swipe view which generates up to 3 all which replicate the original page known in my code as page_fragment_layout.xml. I want to take this a step further a be able to link different pages containing a range of content. In this case I want to be able to link my Activity_main.xml and page_fragment_layout.xml together by swipe. I have added my code so far I would be most appreciative of any input.

MainActivity.java

```
package socialdeveloper.swipecard;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
ViewPager viewPager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
SwipeAdapter swipeAdapter = new SwipeAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(swipeAdapter);
}
}
```

PageFragment.java

```
package socialdeveloper.swipecard;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


/**
* A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
*/
public class PageFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
TextView textView;

public PageFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =     inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_fragment_layout,container,false);
    textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.TestText);

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    String message = Integer.toString(bundle.getInt("count"));
    textView.setText("This is the "+message+ "Swipe View Page...");

    return view;
}

}
```

SwipeAdapter.java

```
package socialdeveloper.swipecard;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

/**
* Created by Hadleigh on 07/12/2015.
 */
public class SwipeAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {


public SwipeAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = new PageFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    int i = 0;
    bundle.putInt("count",i+1);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your **SwipeAdapter.java** use this

```
 `   public Fragment getItem(int position) {
         Fragment fragment = null;//Creates a fragment variable to hold the fragment class i create and make it a null so i can catch the error

       if (position == 0) {
            fragment = new PUT_THE_TITLE_OF_YOUR_ACTIVITY_YOU_WANT_TO_USE();//Calls the fragment.
        }

       if (position == 1) {
            fragment = new CALL_A_DIFFERENT_FRAGMENT_OR_ACTIVITY();//Calls the fragment;
        }

       if (position == 2) {
            fragment = new CALL_A_DIFFERENT_FRAGMENT_OR_ACTIVITY();//Calls the fragment.
        }
    return fragment;
}`
```

in the **getItem()** method to call other fragments or activities.